# Processing/Initializing 2D Array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to write a program for my CS class and am having a problem. In the code below I keep getting an error message at `initializeArray(firstArray)` and `initializeArray(secondArray)`.

The message says `the method initializeArray(int[][]) is undefined for type processArray`.  Can anybody explain to me what I am doing wrong here. I need to be able to call the method initializeArray in my processArray method.

```
public class ProcessArray {


    // The constructor for the class: it initializes the attributes "rows" and "columns", and also completes the 
    // declarations for the two arrays using the dimensions received. It then calls a private method in the class
    // to set the values in both arrays to 0.
    public ProcessArray (int rows, int columns){

        int[][] firstArray = new int[rows][columns];
        int[][] secondArray = new int[rows][columns];

        initializeArray(firstArray);
        initializeArray(secondArray);

    }



    // This private utility method sets the values in both arrays to 0.
    private void intializeArray(int[][] array){

        int rows = array.length;
        int columns = array[0].length;

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            array[i][0] = 0;

            for(int j = 0; j< columns; j++){
                array[i][j] = 0;
            }



        }

    }
```

Comment: You have a typo in method name. Also array[i][0] = 0; is redundant.

Comment: Your redundant statement got me curious. So would the code do the exact same thing without that statement?

Comment: Yes. Go through the iteration in your head. In the first iteration i=0 so array[i][0] is actually array[0][0] = 0; then you come to the line array[i][j] = 0, both i and j are 0 so you do array[0][0] = 0 again.

Comment: That is what I thought after you first mentioned it just wanted to confirm. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

intializeArray

initializeArray

are spelled in a different way

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot.  Thank you though you just saved me alot of time looking for other reasons haha